# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY when want to get data into recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have a json. I have to get `source_url` into my recyclerView -

```
     [{
      "id":3110,
      "date":"2020-05-07T18:33:44",
      "date_gmt":"2020-05-07T18:33:44",
      "modified":"2020-05-07T18:35:37",
      "modified_gmt":"2020-05-07T18:35:37",
      "_embedded":{
             "wp:featuredmedia":[
{
               "id":3111,
               "date":"2020-05-07T18:33:08",
               "slug":"prof-dr-abul-khair",
               "source_url":"https:\/\/www.healthmen.com.bd\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2020\/05\/Prof.-Dr.-Abul-Khair-scaled.jpg"
}]
            }  
}]
```

I want to get `source_url` from this JSON
But, here is an array `wp:featuredmedia`. So that, I  followed this process-

Created a class named FeaturedMedia -

```
      public class FeaturedMedia {
        @SerializedName("source_url")
        @Expose
        private String souceurl;
        public String getSourceurl(){
            return sourceurl;
}
        }
```

Then, I created another class named MediaDetails where I take the FeaturedMedia as a List-

```
 public class MediaDetails{
    @SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia")
    List<FeaturedMedia> featureMediaList;
    public List<FeaturedMedia> getFeaturedMediaList(){
    return featuredMediaList;
    }}
```

Then the Model Class-

```
public class Model{
 @SerializedName("id")
@Expose
int id;
@SerializedName("_embedded")
@Expose
MediaDetalis embedded;

public int getId(){
return id;
}
public MediaDetails getEmbedded(){
return embedded;
}}
```

After all, I created RecyclerViewAdapter to get the data-

```
public CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomAdapterHolder{
List<Model> modelList;
public void  onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapterHolder holder, int position){

final Model model=modelList.get(position);
int id= model.getId():
String embedded= String.valurOf(model.getEmbedded.getFeaturedMediaList());
}
```

But, embedded can not get the `source_url` value. I completed this CustomAdapter. Here I just presented needed code of that adapter. How can I get the `source_url` value in this RecyclerView?

Comment: share valid json please.

Comment: now, check the JSON

Comment: Invalid JSON variable. Kindly rectify

Comment: Now , check the JSON. I formatted it in JSON Formatter

Answer (score 0):

Your **POJO** class will be (Respect to given JSON)

```
 public class Model {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("date_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateGmt;
    @SerializedName("modified")
    @Expose
    private String modified;
    @SerializedName("modified_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String modifiedGmt;
    @SerializedName("_embedded")
    @Expose
    private Embedded embedded;

    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
    return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDateGmt() {
    return dateGmt;
    }

    public void setDateGmt(String dateGmt) {
    this.dateGmt = dateGmt;
    }

    public String getModified() {
    return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(String modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
    }

    public String getModifiedGmt() {
    return modifiedGmt;
    }

    public void setModifiedGmt(String modifiedGmt) {
    this.modifiedGmt = modifiedGmt;
    }

    public Embedded getEmbedded() {
    return embedded;
    }

    public void setEmbedded(Embedded embedded) {
    this.embedded = embedded;
    }

    }
```

Then **Embedded** class

```
public class Embedded {

    @SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia")
    @Expose
    private List<WpFeaturedmedium> wpFeaturedmedia = null;

    public List<WpFeaturedmedium> getWpFeaturedmedia() {
    return wpFeaturedmedia;
    }

    public void setWpFeaturedmedia(List<WpFeaturedmedium> wpFeaturedmedia) {
    this.wpFeaturedmedia = wpFeaturedmedia;
    }

    }
```

Then **WpFeaturedmedium**

```
public class WpFeaturedmedium {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    @Expose
    private String slug;
    @SerializedName("source_url")
    @Expose
    private String sourceUrl;

    public Integer getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
    return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getSourceUrl() {
    return sourceUrl;
    }

    public void setSourceUrl(String sourceUrl) {
    this.sourceUrl = sourceUrl;
    }

    }
```

Check - [**`How to create POJO class`**](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: how can In I get the source_url  value in RecyclerView

Comment: @ImtiazRiad Solved this yet?

Comment: Yeah. It's solved yesterday. Sorry to late to inform you. Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion. Brother.

Comment: @ImtiazRiad You can accept this answer if helpful/works.